# Why are my soft tabs showing as hard tabs?

Tags: linux, tabs, visual-studio-code

I am editing files in VSCode (version 1.16.0) which were originally created in Emacs with indent-tabs-mode set to STANDARD. This was not set by me, but inherited, and, as far as I could tell, spaces were being inserted.  Every indentation was 3 spaces, and the TAB key was used to achieve the indentation. That is what you saw in Emacs or if you more/cat the file from a command prompt.  Like such:

```
data a;
   set b;
   x = 3;
run;
```

We have recently moved from a Solaris environment to Linux (Redhat 6) and, for a number of reasons, it behooves me to stop using Emacs in favor of VSCode. I have `"editor.detectIndentation": false` set in VSCode, with tabs inserting spaces, and the number of spaces set to 3.

When I open up these files in VSCode, however, the indentation looks off, like

```
data a;
        set b;
   x = 3;
run;
```

and, thus, I've begun a process where I am re-indenting everything, so they will look right in the VSCode world. The fact that this will create a bunch of whitespace-difference noise in version control is irrelevant in this particular case. Progress demands we move on and live with some short-term pain in that regard.

So, I delete all indentation and re-indent with the tab settings outlined above and all looks well in VSCode. Everything's lined up. I have 3 spaces per indent. Back to my first example above.

However, if I more/cat out the code now, it appears as if hard tabs have been used, so it looks awful (like my second example). And we do a lot of quick code inspection thru this means, so it's a highly undesirable effect.  Why is this happening?

Everything I've seen online focuses on how VSCode handles soft/hard tabs, or problems with that functionality. Essentially, people are asking how to get the settings to what I've set above. I haven't seen anyone with my problem -- i.e. I believe I have the VSCode setting correct, it looks good and proper in VSCode, but looks like hard tabs were inserted instead of spaces when a simple more/cat is performed. (As a side note, if I open the files in Emacs after this, it also looks like hard tabs were used)

Comment: All of my installations of VS Code handle tabs properly. I have it set so VS Code makes tabs two spaces, and it works.

Comment: In Emacs do you have `indent-tabs-mode` set to `nil`?

Comment: No, it is set to STANDARD, so that explains Emacs.  But that doesn't explain why just more-ing out from the command line shows hard tabs, too

Comment: Also, I have "editor.detectIndentation": false set in VSCode, so even thought these files were originally edited in Emacs, this setting should take care of that, right?

Comment: you can use the `untabify` Emacs command to transform tabs into space. Maybe this can help you to fix some buffers.

Comment: I've removed the [emacs] tag, as it seems to me that *how* you created the file in the first place is irrelevant to this question about how VSCode handles tabs (although possibly indicative that you also have *separate* questions to ask about how to configure indentation in Emacs).